# How can I create path folders from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that contains folders names with paragraph numbers (extracted from a word file with pydocx)

```
list = [
"1. Références",
"2. Identification de l’équipement sous test",
"3. Moyens de test",
"4. Configurations matérielle et logicielle",
"4.1. Configuration matérielle de base",
"4.2. Configuration Application",
"file1.txt",
"file2.txt",
"5. Tests fonctionnels",
"5.1. Démarrage",
"5.2. Réglages",
"file1.txt",
"file2.txt",
"file3.txt",
"5.3. Signalisation",
"file1.txt",
"file2.txt",
"file3.txt",
"file4.txt",
"5.3.1. LED Focus",
"file1.txt",
"file2.txt",
"file3.txt",
"file4.txt",
"file5.txt",
"5.3.2. LED Verrou",
"5.3.3. LED Apprentissage",
"5.3.4. LED Fin de course",
"5.3.5. LED Défaut",
"5.3.6. LED Fonctionnement",
"5.3.7. Buzzer",
"5.4. Bornier Commande",
"5.4.1. Sans fonction",
"5.4.1.1. Entrée E1",
"5.4.1.2. Entrée E2",
.
.
.
]
```

I want to convert these elements to path directories, in order to create a tree folders.
for example:
I want to have folder directories like this:

- "/4.Configurations matérielle et logicielle/4.1. Configuration matérielle de base/"
- "/4.Configurations matérielle et logicielle/4.2. Configuration
  Application/file1.txt"
- "/4.Configurations matérielle et logicielle/4.2. Configuration
  Application/file2.txt"
- "/5. Tests fonctionnels/5.1. Démarrage/"
- "/5. Tests fonctionnels/5.2. Réglages/file1.txt"
- "/5. Tests fonctionnels/5.2. Réglages/file2.txt"

and so one ...

I really appreciate your suggestion, cause I've tired every think, but i didnt get what I want.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you explain how `python-requests` (which is used as tag) is related to your question?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please be aware this is not a code-writing service. We can help solving specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain everything here:

- Verify if the first value of every element in your list is a file or a directory.
- If the element is a file add it into your paths folder using your **parentStack**. I used a **tuple** for that *(Number of the directory, Complete name of the directory, If the directory it is in your path list of not)*, for example, *("5.5.", "5.5. Directory Example", False)*.
- If the **parentStack** is empty and your element is a directory add it into your stack.
- If your stack is not empty check if the **last element of your stack** is the **parent directory** of your current element. If it is the parent add it into your stack. If it does not, remove the last element and check if that element has been added into your **paths list**.

There is the code:

```
import re
paths = []
parentStack = []

def addPath(value, isDirectory):
    path = ""
    for i in range(len(parentStack)):
        path += "/" + parentStack[i][1] # Complete name folder
        parentStack[i] = (parentStack[i][0], parentStack[i][1], True)
    path += "/" + value
    if isDirectory:
        path += "/"
    paths.append(path)

def returnPaths(list):
    for elem in list:
        value = elem.split(" ")[0] # Taking the number directory
        if re.match("([0-9]+\.)+", value) == None:
            addPath(elem, False)
        else:
            if not parentStack:
                parentStack.append((value, elem, False)) 
            else:
                added = False
                while parentStack:
                    isSon = True
                    parent = parentStack[-1][0] # I'm taking the number of the directory here

                    for i in range(len(parent)):
                        if (len(value) > i and parent[i] != value[i]):
                            folder = parentStack.pop()
                            isSon = False
                            if not folder[2]:
                                addPath(folder[1], True)
                            break

                    if isSon:
                        added = True
                        parentStack.append((value, elem, False))
                        break
                if not added:
                    parentStack.append((value, elem, False))
    return paths
```